# Why are female steroid-using bodybuilders less muscular than male ones?

Tags: bodybuilding, hormones

Given that steroids and growth hormone etc. are taken by both male and female bodybuilders, why are the male bodybuilders always more muscular?

Presumably women's doses aren't lower than men's. Also, although men naturally have more testosterone than women, I've read that taking artificial hormones causes all natural testosterone production to stop, due to negative feedback. So natural testosterone can't be the explanation.

Comment: Do you have any data on muscle weight/overall weight ratio for male and female bodybuilders? I think we also need to compare training intensity, calorie/hormone/steroids/protein intake to answer your question. I believe your observations are true, but it'll be interesting  to see the numbers.

Comment: I think it depends on your definition of "muscular".  I've seen some pretty amazing female bodybuilders that look better than some men in the same weight category.

Comment: What do you mean why?
There is X vs Y chromosome difference that  explains all the differences between sexes.

Answer (score 1):

Although we'd like to think the sexes are equal, when it comes to physiology, we are in fact quite different from one another. So the same nutrient or supplement may not have the exact same response in the body, primarily due to our hormonal differences (testosterone, estrogen, etc.). I highly recommend reading the mars/venus diet solution written by Dr. John Gray for a really user-friendly look at how different the sexes are both mentally and physically.

Answer (score 1):

Some women get really big, and are biggest than 90% of males in the fitness industry. However just adding testosterone isn't enough to eliminate the physiological difference between the sexes.

Answer (score 1):

The natural testosterone level in male, is around 200-1200ng/dl, while in women is around 15-70ng/dl. There is a significant diference here, and this is the reason why women have it quite dificult to gain muscle.

Anyway, using steroids as you say, stops the endogenous testosterone production. Here is where a woman has to consider if she wants to mantain some femininity, or if she doesn't care about that. Usually the steroids doses in women are much lower than in men, to not lose this femeninity, but you can also find women who look like real men.